# python: iterate through dynamic list

Tags: python, list, dynamic, iterable

From a set of sequences (strings), I want to generate a dictionary of subsets where each of the sequences represents a key, and the values should be all sequences that match at most at "match" (e.g. 1) positions, both with the original sequence (key), and also with all value entries that are in the subset at that time.

For example, considering all sequences of length 3 consisting of "A", "C" and "G" and "T", one of the key, value pairs should be (or could be, since there are more possible way to select such a set).

This is the definition I came up with:

```
def pick(seq,superset):
    subset = [seq]
    for seq in subset:
        count = 0
        for item in superset:
            if len([i for i, j in zip(list(seq),list(item)) if i==j])==match:
                count += 1
                if len(subset)==count:
                    subset += [''.join(item)]
    return subset
```

what I get:

```
{'AAA': ['AAA', 'ACC', 'ACG', 'ACT', 'AGC', 'AGG', 'AGT', 'ATC', 'ATG', 'ATT', 'CAC', 'CAG',
'CAT', 'CCA', 'CGA', 'CTA', 'GAC', 'GAG', 'GAT', 'GCA', 'GGA', 'GTA', 'TAC', 'TAG', 'TAT',
'TCA', 'TGA', 'TTA']}
```

What I want:

```
{'AAA': ['CCC','GGG','TTT','ACG','CGT','GTA','TAC']}
```

The issue I run into, is that I now only generate a subset where the values match no more than at one position with the key, but the value sequences do have more than one positions specific match with other values in the subset. Does anyone have a(n elegant) solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking, but in general it's unsafe to remove items from a list at the same time as you're iterating over it. This will confuse the iterator variable and may cause some items to seemingly be skipped. Consider a different approach that doesn't require `for item in copy: copy.remove(item)`.

Comment: thanks Kevin, I have now changed that. This does not solve the issue I had, I had it in there because I thought it would save me time not having to iterate over items that I could already discard after the first loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm interpreting your question as "I want to get a list of all items in `superset` that have somewhere between 0 and `match` matching characters with `seq`. But right now my function returns a list of all items that have *exactly* `match` matching characters. Also the first element of the returned list is equal to `seq`, which I don't want."

The first problem occurs because you use "==" when comparing to match, instead of "<=". The second problem occurs because you initialize `subset` to contain `seq` even though you don't need to. It's also unnecessary to have two `for` loops. Also, consider using `append` instead of `+=` when adding items to a list, as it is almost always more efficient.

```
def pick(seq,superset,match):
    subset = []
    for item in superset:
        if len([i for i, j in zip(list(seq),list(item)) if i==j])<=match:
            subset.append(''.join(item))
    return subset

superset = [
    'GGG', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGT', 'GCG', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCT', 'GAG', 'GAC', 'GAA', 'GAT', 'GTG', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTT', 
    'CGG', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGT', 'CCG', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCT', 'CAG', 'CAC', 'CAA', 'CAT', 'CTG', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTT', 
    'AGG', 'AGC', 'AGA', 'AGT', 'ACG', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACT', 'AAG', 'AAC', 'AAA', 'AAT', 'ATG', 'ATC', 'ATA', 'ATT', 
    'TGG', 'TGC', 'TGA', 'TGT', 'TCG', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCT', 'TAG', 'TAC', 'TAA', 'TAT', 'TTG', 'TTC', 'TTA', 'TTT'
]

seq = "AAA"

print pick(seq, superset, 1)
```

Result (newlines added by me for clarity):

```
['GGG', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGT', 'GCG', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCT', 'GAG', 'GAC', 'GAT', 'GTG', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTT', 
'CGG', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGT', 'CCG', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCT', 'CAG', 'CAC', 'CAT', 'CTG', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTT', 
'AGG', 'AGC', 'AGT', 'ACG', 'ACC', 'ACT', 'ATG', 'ATC', 'ATT', 
'TGG', 'TGC', 'TGA', 'TGT', 'TCG', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCT', 'TAG', 'TAC', 'TAT', 'TTG', 'TTC', 'TTA', 'TTT']
```

---

Edit: if each potential item must also satisfy the matching criteria with every other existing element of the subset, you can check this using `all` and a list comprehension. Note that the value returned by the function will depend on the order of `superset`, since there are multiple different local maxima that could satisfy the criteria.

```
def similarity(a,b):
    return sum(1 for p,q in zip(a,b) if p==q)

def pick(seq, superset, match):
    subset = []
    for item in superset:
        if similarity(item, seq) <= match and all(similarity(item, x) <= match for x in subset):
            subset.append(item)
    return subset

superset = [
    'GGG', 'GGC', 'GGA', 'GGT', 'GCG', 'GCC', 'GCA', 'GCT', 'GAG', 'GAC', 'GAA', 'GAT', 'GTG', 'GTC', 'GTA', 'GTT', 
    'CGG', 'CGC', 'CGA', 'CGT', 'CCG', 'CCC', 'CCA', 'CCT', 'CAG', 'CAC', 'CAA', 'CAT', 'CTG', 'CTC', 'CTA', 'CTT', 
    'AGG', 'AGC', 'AGA', 'AGT', 'ACG', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACT', 'AAG', 'AAC', 'AAA', 'AAT', 'ATG', 'ATC', 'ATA', 'ATT', 
    'TGG', 'TGC', 'TGA', 'TGT', 'TCG', 'TCC', 'TCA', 'TCT', 'TAG', 'TAC', 'TAA', 'TAT', 'TTG', 'TTC', 'TTA', 'TTT'
]

seq = "AAA"

print pick(seq, superset, 1)
```

Result:

```
['GGG', 'GCC', 'GAT', 'GTA', 'CGC', 'CCG', 'CTT', 'AGT', 'ATG', 'TGA', 'TCT', 'TAG', 'TTC']
```

Comment: It still return a set in which sequences match other sequences within that subset at more than 1 position though. I have update my question with the output I get, and the output that I need.

Comment: great, that is what exactly what I was looking for. I cannot +1 you since I'm not very reputable, so I hope someone else will ;)

Comment: That's fine :-) feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it was useful to you.

Comment: okay, done. Interestingly though, you get stuck at local optima, meaning that some keys have a list of sequences that is longer than that of others. There is probably a way around this too, but I do not necessarily needs this. If you're up for it you're welcome to try to get to give it a try, ensuring that all values contain 15 elements, I would find this interesting to learn, but I think it will be pretty difficult. The easiest solution I can think of is to generate multiple subsets per key and select the longest one.